Adding Notes to Header Cell when generating csv with CSVPrinter
Is it possible to add notes(this yellow flyouts) or comments to a specific cell when generating a CSV (Excel Format) with Apache CSV Printer?
what method or workaround could I use in order to have a note displayed?
I right now generate the file with CSVPrinter I have a Header. On one Header cell there should be a note displayed when you hover over it.
Can this be achieved with CSVPrinter?

CSV stands for comma separated values. A header like "name, number", and then rows of names and numbers, separated by a comma. That's it. No room for sticky notes. You can open a csv file in your favorite editor. Any comments, charts, formula, and so on do only exist in the real spreadsheet program formats, like .xls files. If you want anything besides plain data, you need to create those formats.
